# How to split Json Web Token as Header-Payload-Signature in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, jwt

I have node.js application. I use Json Web Token for autherization. JWT has three parts named header, payload and signature. There is a dot between these parts as shown in the below.

```
token = header.payload.signature  ||  token= xxxxx.yyyyyy.zzzzz

token = eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

I need to get the payload value (the middle part) from the created token of header. I need to split the token as 3 parts (Header-Payload-Signature).

I use this method:

```
const token= req.headers.authorization.split("")[1];
header,payload,signature = token.split('.')
```

But this doesn't work. Is there any other splitting method or suggestion for me ?

**EDIT: It can be considered as I have a string (which is basically a file name following a naming convention) abc.def.ghi**

**I would like to extract the substring before the first . (ie a dot)**

**In javascript, How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path. You can split your token like this:

Basic HTML just to test:

```
<div id="app">
<p id="head"></p>
<p id="pay"></p>
<p id="sign"></p>
</div>
```

Actual javascript code:

```js
var token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"

var [header, payload, signature] = token.split(".")

document.getElementById("head").innerHTML= `header: ${header}`
document.getElementById("pay").innerHTML =`payload: ${payload}`
document.getElementById("sign").innerHTML= `signature: ${signature}`
```

Comment: Thank you ! I just forgot to put [] brackles